# Resize electron.js app from draggable css area

Tags: css, electron

My app uses a frameless window and I made a custom title bar along with it, I set the entire titlebar area to be draggable with `-webkit-app-region: drag;` so you can position the window on the desktop, but now I can't resize the app from those corners, is there any way to keep both?

[image: Title bar]

Edit: I added `-webkit-app-region: drag;` to the buttons and the left title area because I lost control of the buttons and I can resize from corners and those edges, but the top edge is still inactive

Comment: I can resize my window's top edge using a custom title bar on Linux. Can you include what platform you're testing on?

Comment: Windows 11 dev channel build

Comment: It'd be worth testing your app on a Windows **10** computer to see if this bug is just a Windows 11 bug.
Either way creating a minimal reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: Can't really try on a windows 10 system, I quess I can upload the project to github and send you the link to it?

Comment: Yes that sounds good. I have a Windows 10 computer with me.

Comment: [title-bar-broke](https://github.com/Ontley/title-bar-broke) here it is